# Magento 1.9 Import/Export modules delivers no feedback during the import

Tags: magento-1.9, import, importexport

Dear Magento community,

the ImportExport core module (not the slow DataFlow, but the "new" one which was introduced by 1.5) doesn't deliver any status information of import progress. I'm trying to import **over 100k lines of customer data**, which is why I cannot opt to MAGMI or any other reasonable alternative solution I'm aware of.

So I have to wait hours for the check of CSV file to finish only to get to know, that in the end over 100 lines are invalid (which is really not much, if you consider the file size).

Does someone have an idea, how I can add at least some primitive logging or on-screen information, which tells me some information about the check or import POST-request on the fly? E.g. how many lines were checked, where are errors etc. At least so much, that I can tell, that the scripts didn't stuck somewhere...

Many thanks for your feedback and kind regads,
Dimitri

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this module: https://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/.

Obviously, the shell import takes much less time than an import via Magento admin - my dataset with over 100k customer data was imported successfully in approx. 30 minutes via SSH.